# Bit Testing.Counting the bits

Tags: c, bit

Why does it print that bit number 6 of 47(00101111) is 1.Counting the bits starts from the right side starting with 1?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int mask1,mask2;

        //bit  testing;
        mask1=1<<3;
        mask2=1<<6;
        if(47&mask1!=0)
            printf("\n bit number 3 is 1");
        else
            printf("\n bit number 3 is 0");
        if(47&mask2!=0)
            printf("\n bit number 6 is 1");
        else
             printf("\n bit number 6 is 0");

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

The bitwise AND operator `&` has lower precedence than the inequality operator `!=`.  So this:

```
47&mask1!=0
```

Is the same as:

```
47&(mask1!=0)
```

Add parenthesis as follows:

```
(47&mask1)!=0
```

And you'll get the expected results.  Be sure to do the same for the check against `mask2`.